# background service to send a notification and when the user clicks the notification it must launch the appropriate activity

Tags: android

I am developing a small app in which I want a background service to send a notification and when the user clicks the notification it must launch the appropriate activity. I am posting the code here for the notification and my problem is **that the notification gets displayed on the status bar but when i click it it does not launch the required activity(instead it is launching the mainactivity)**. Can somebody suggest where I am going wrong. Please help.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, IncidentDetail.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this,0  /* Request code */
            , intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 //here i tried with both getService and getActivity
  /*PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0 
            , intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);*/

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(Title)
                    .setContentText(messageBody)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    ;

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Below is my manifest file

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <activity
        android:name=".IncidentDetail"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_incident_detail"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
    </activity>
```

Comment: did you tried swiping the notification because same happened to me but when i swiped the notification it opened the activity and my target version is oreo.

Answer (score 1):

Problem in this line.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this,0  /* Request code */
        , intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

It shoule be.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0  /* Request code */
        , intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Cause Intent is  calling an activity not a service .

Comment: please check the question, it is already mentioned. But that is also not useful. Any other idea

Comment: Yeah i saw that .  for Which android version ?you have tested

Comment: testing on android 7.1.1 and compileSdkVersion 23 , buildToolsVersion "23.0.0", targetSdkVersion 23

Comment: Did you checked after kill the application ? try after close your app also from recent and then check notification click .

Comment: yes i tried kill the application but still the problem not resolved. I am tring to open an activity by clicking on notification (this notification is generated by a service class)

Comment: Well if notification is implemented by FCM . First thing are you sure your code is calling? Cause FCM notification messages are automatically handled by FCM SDK .First make sure that your notification builder's  code is calling. Then I'll look into your code .

Comment: Thanks. Now i able to open desired activity using click_action parameter in PHP scirpt and getting the click action value in the service class using  
  intent as Intent intent = new Intent(remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction().toString());